# How do I drop requests from dig?

Tags: linux, centos, security, iptables, firewall

Basically I'm getting tons of request to my named/bind service,
basically those requests are being rejected by named,
Those are the messages i get, from tons of ips., How extacly can I drop those requests insted of rejecting them , Thanks in Advance.

```
Jan 20 16:43:01 lexneva named[2704]: client 66.230.160.1#7699: query (cache) './NS/IN' denied
Jan 20 16:43:01 lexneva named[2704]: client 66.230.160.1#13391: query (cache) './NS/IN' denied
Jan 20 16:43:02 lexneva named[2704]: client 66.230.128.15#43014: query (cache) './NS/IN' denied
Jan 20 16:43:04 lexneva named[2704]: client 66.230.128.15#45178: query (cache) './NS/IN' denied
```

Comment: Why do you want that? Are you hitting any resource limits? It is part of the protocol to deny these requests.

Comment: Yes sir, they are spamming my server i do not want to reject, i want to drop those requests

Answer (score 0):

There are at least a couple ways you could achieve that.

I've seen examples of using iptables with its string/bytes-matching functionality to look for recursive queries coming from outside, and then dropping them. I've a colleague that did that on an authoritative non-recursive server for a number of years and he said it works well.

I've also seen people using something like fail2ban to look at the logs, determine that an evil IP/subnet was doing something undesirable, and let it put in rules to block the client at the firewall.

Comment: how to make it?

Comment: This looks useful. http://blog.dataforce.org.uk/2013/08/limiting-the-effectiveness-of-dns-amplification/

Answer (score -1):

```
#> iptables -I INPUT -s 66.230.160.1 -j DROP
#> iptables -I INPUT -s 66.230.160.15 -j DROP
```

Comment: I wish it was one ip bro, it like crazy plenty of ip's

Comment: haha that's no fun.  You can drop an entire subnet :
`iptables -I INPUT -s 66.230.160.0/24 -j DROP`

Comment: they are not attacking from same subnet lol,.... this is just stupid., this guy probably got plenty of zombies or whatever

Comment: You could setup a flood limit on the BIND port which will essentially act as a DNS only ddos control  and you could setup the rules and then change the threshold